# Java : Signals not handled

Tags: java, android, exception, signals

I get a crash in my app. The log says :

```
 12-17 09:26:53.414  5330  7177 F libc    : Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS) at 0x0000a000 (code=2), thread 7011 (thread-pool-2)
    12-17 09:26:53.424  5330  9658 W System.err: Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: read failed: EIO (I/O error)
    12-17 09:26:53.424  5330  9658 W System.err:    at libcore.io.Posix.readBytes(Native Method)
    12-17 09:26:53.424  5330  9658 W System.err:    at libcore.io.Posix.read(Posix.java:127)
    12-17 09:26:53.424  5330  9658 W System.err:    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.read(BlockGuardOs.java:149)
    12-17 09:26:53.424  5330  9658 W System.err:    at libcore.io.IoBridge.read(IoBridge.java:425)
    12-17 09:26:53.424  5330  9658 W System.err:    ... 7 more
    12-17 09:26:53.444  5330  9666 W System.err: java.io.IOException: read failed: EIO (I/O error)
    12-17 09:26:53.444  5330  9666 W System.err:    at libcore.io.IoBridge.read(IoBridge.java:435)
    12-17 09:26:53.444  5330  9666 W System.err:    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.read(RandomAccessFile.java:290)
```

The relevant code where I get the error is run in a separate thread (Asynctask) and it has exception handling done. My question is, why does my app still crash ? Shouldn't there be an IOException thrown, which is then handled ? Is this saying that even the VM itself was caught unaware and closed by the OS ?

What is the correct way to handle this - is it even possible at all from an app developer POV ?

BTW this is Android v4.3

TIA